# Hyperlinking only if web address present..?

Tags: xml, xslt

Following is sample XML File -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Catalog>
<Book>
   <AName>Steven Holzner</AName>
   <BName>Using XSLT</BName>
   <Pub>ABC Publication </Pub>
   <Web>http://www.ABCPub.com</Web>
</Book>
<Book>
   <AName>Steven Holzner</AName>
   <BName>Using HTML</BName>
   <Pub>XYZ Publication </Pub>
   <Web></Web>
</Book>
</Catalog>
```

I want to hyperlink the Pub name if Web address is given, other wise only Pub name w/o a link...

My XSL code is here -

```
<xsl:template match="Catalog">
    <xsl:for-each select="Book">
    <p><a>
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
      <xsl:value-of select="Web"/>
    </xsl:attribute>

    <xsl:value-of select="Pub"/>
    </a></p>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

I want following HTML source -

<p><a href="http://www.ABCPub.com">ABC Publication</a></p>
<p>XYZ Publication</a></p>

Rightnow, this XSL gives hyperlink tag even if Web addr is not given..
What piece of code will do the needful..?

have a nice day - 
John

Comment: Good question, +1. XSLT is a powerful and very expressive language that makes it possible to solve this problem in a minimum number of lines without any conditionals, looping constructs or separate attribute-generating instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This can be achieved with a very short and simple transformation -- no `<xsl:for-each>`, no `<xsl:if>`, `<xsl:choose>`, `<xsl:when>`,no `<xsl:attribute>` at all**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="Book[Web/text()]">
     <p>
      <a href="{Web}">
       <xsl:value-of select="Pub"/>
      </a>
     </p>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Book">
     <p>
       <xsl:value-of select="Pub"/>
     </p>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Catalog>
    <Book>
        <AName>Steven Holzner</AName>
        <BName>Using XSLT</BName>
        <Pub>ABC Publication </Pub>
        <Web>http://www.ABCPub.com</Web>
    </Book>
    <Book>
        <AName>Steven Holzner</AName>
        <BName>Using HTML</BName>
        <Pub>XYZ Publication </Pub>
        <Web></Web>
    </Book>
</Catalog>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<p>
   <a href="http://www.ABCPub.com">ABC Publication </a>
</p>
<p>XYZ Publication </p>
```

**Explanation**: Template pattern matching.

Comment: Finally some AVT's :-) Very nice Dimitre. +1

Answer (score 1):

Just test if the Web is filled with choose/when/else

```
<xsl:template match="Catalog">
    <xsl:for-each select="Book">
    <p><xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="string(Web)"><a>
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
      <xsl:value-of select="Web"/>
    </xsl:attribute>

    <xsl:value-of select="Pub"/>
    </a>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:value-of select="Pub"/>
</xsl:othwerwise>
</xsl:choose>
</p>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:if test="Web != ''">
   <a> 
    <xsl:attribute name="href"> 
      <xsl:value-of select="Web"/> 
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="Pub"/> 
    </a>
</xsl:if>
```

^That will display the publisher only if there is a web address, what you want is an xsl:choose...

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="Web != ''">
        <a> 
        <xsl:attribute name="href"> 
          <xsl:value-of select="Web"/> 
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="Pub"/> 
        </a>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="Pub"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sheldo, rightnow 2nd of yours is sufficient for me. the 1st one might come to rescue in future ;).. Thanks a lot again..